# Spring Boot + Apache Camel + AWS Lambda with multiple lambda endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, apache-camel

I am learning Apache Camel and how to use it with Spring Boot. I have been able to successfully hit one lambda function using Camel and Spring and so far it works great. However I'm having trouble when I try to add a second function that I want to hit using a different route.

At a core, the problem I'm having is that it seems Camel requires that the property `camel.component.aws-lambda.configuration.function` is defined in order to create an endpoint. But obviously I don't want to define that property because I need to have multiple functions, not just a single one.

Current code that works:

application.yaml:

```
camel:
  component:
    aws-lambda:
      configuration:
        access-key: myAccessKey
        secret-key: mySecretKey
        region: MY_REGION
        function: myFunction
        operation: invokeFunction
```

My route:

```
@Component
public class MessageTestInvocationRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("somewhere").routeId("lambda")
                .to("aws-lambda://myFunction");
    }
}
```

Now how can I add a second route? As soon as I comment out the `camel.component.aws-lambda.configuration.function` property, my existing route breaks due to an NPE. But if I leave that property defined, then it seems all AWS calls will be tied to that one function.

I have tried looking into making custom `LambdaComponent`s, I have tried looking into making custom `AWSLambdaClient`s, none of these did anything useful - it all falls apart as soon as I comment out that property.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? And are you sure you must set function in the yaml file? I think its just there as a default function name.

Comment: Camel version is 3.0.0. And I am sure that I must set the function in the yaml file simply because if I remove it, then I start getting NPE errors because seems like Camel doesn't create some "Endpoint" object. I also would think that it's just the default function name, but removing it breaks everything.

Comment: Okay so the component level (eg in your yaml file) should not have any effect. We will remove this option from Camel 3.1 onwards: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14328

Comment: Can you post the NPE stacktrace you get?

Comment: Here's the NPE:

https://pastebin.com/raw/SbGEAhwH

From looking at the code it looks like there is an `Endpoint` object that is null.

Comment: Let me provide a little bit more detail, because I'm not convinced that I'm not just doing something wrong. If I remove ALL of the `camel.component.aws-lambda.configuration` properties, then I get a different error message: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: accessKey/secretKey or awsLambdaClient must be specified`. I added a different `Endpoint` bean with these properties specified, but still got the error.

This is why I tried to only remove the `function` and `operation` properties, which resulted in the NPE.

Comment: It might simply be that I am not providing the proper beans, which is why Camel / Spring Boot then tries to use the one defined in the `application.yaml` file, and if that's not present or completely defined then I get the errors.

Comment: Follow up - I removed all the properties from the `application.yaml` file, and was getting the `accessKey/secretKey or awsLambdaClient must be specified` error - so I created an `AWSLambdaClient` bean. After doing this, I once again was getting the NPE, so I think there might be indeed some issue because it looks to me like I have all the proper beans defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason I was getting an NPE is because I did not have an operation defined. When the function and operation are defined in `application.yaml`, then Spring attempts to use that one, which is why commenting out those properties caused that issue. The solution was to comment out the `function` and `operation` properties, and then change my route code to:

```
@Component
public class MessageTestInvocationRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("somewhere").routeId("lambda")
                .to("aws-lambda://myFunction?operation=invokeFunction");
    }
}
```

Now I am able to create multiple routes that all function just fine in parallel.

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah lets make invoke function the default operation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14330